# Blank screen after start up logo, fans get loud. Typing this from Safe Mode. I don't have an installation CD. What are my options?

Tags: windows-7, boot

So when my laptop starts up you get to see the "Starting Windows" logo and then the screen goes black indefinitely. There is no loading bar that you usually see. The fans get loud as I assume a lot of CPU is being used up.

I've tried:

1. System repair. It failed to find anything wrong.
2. Restore from restore point (restores fine but when you get to the start up same black screen occurs).

My laptop did not come with an installation CD but I want to refrain from doing a fresh install as much as possible.

What are my options here? Is there a diagnostic log I can produce for you guys?

EDIT: Is it safe to do an in-place upgrade to Windows 8 in Safe Mode?

Comment: Are the any logged errors (see then evenlog after booting in safe mode).

Comment: @Hennes I am looking at the Event Viewer right now, where can I find the logged errors?

Comment: If there are none: nowhere. But if 'windows log' 'system' has entries with a red cross though them (error) then read those.